# Calculating Date Difference In XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Note: Please don't mark this as duplicate, hear my question out please

I'm completely new here and I've been running down a mental breakdown on getting a simple date difference between 2 dates from past 2 hours, every answer on the internet doesn't seem to work for me.

Can someone please provide exactly what do i have to put in the XML file and what goes in the XSL file to get the simplistic date difference possible?

Every answer out there just throws one segment of the code but with being new I have no idea where and how to implement it so thanks for understanding my issue :) Hope you can help me

Even if you mark this as duplicate, atleast put it in comment what exactly I have to put in XML file and what exactly goes in XSL file

Comment: I've gone through all of this links and none of them worked because of the vague answers

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169650/how-to-calculate-date-difference-with-xpath-only

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521746/how-to-get-date-difference-in-xslt

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544762/finding-the-difference-between-2-dates-in-xslt

Comment: Is possible to use **xslt 2**?

Comment: yes definitely as long as someone defines How because I've tried alot of things, they all didn't work

Comment: A question that says "I've tried everything and nothing works" is much less likely to get a good answer than one that says "I tried XYZ and it failed saying ABC".

Answer (score 2):

One of the simplest **XSLT 2.0**-date-compare is like this:

**XML:**

```
<dates>
    <date id="1">2016-09-15</date>
    <date id="2">2016-09-10</date>
</dates>
```

**XSLT 2.0:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="dates">
        <xsl:element name="difference">
            <xsl:value-of select="days-from-duration(xs:date(date[@id=1]) - xs:date(date[@id=2]))"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If this does not work, your problem is somewhere other located than the stylesheet. Then you have to state your environment like xslt-processor, software, programming language you are using.

Comment: doesn't work, just shows the data dump of the dates

"2016-09-15 2016-09-10"

Comment: @RadioactiveCoffe, See it online at http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5DU where it is working to compute the difference.

Comment: That's funny, do you have any idea/solution on how I can get it to work on my pc? It just doesn't show up for some reason

Comment: also how does it work? you haven't made any reference to the xsl file
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>

Comment: http://image.prntscr.com/image/e072f905af0f415f8c5207c93a49d988.png

this is what it looks like on mine, if I copy paste the exact same code

Comment: Well, if you have never used XSLT 2.0 then read http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/xslt/1129/introduction-to-xslt/3641/installation-or-setup#t=201609150935232522275 on how to get started, you need an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime or Altova, browsers don't support XSLT 2.0.

Comment: is there any way with xslt 1.0?

Comment: @uL1 This question was tagged by the OP as XSLT 1.0. The answer given requires XSLT 2.0. You have edited the question and added the XSLT 2.0 tag, thus creating this whole mess. Please don't do that again.

Comment: @michael.hor257k see my comment and SO answer under the original question! XSLT 2.0 is possible! so i added the Tag!